# How to know whether cometd client is connected to http or https?

Tags: java, ajax, cometd

I am trying to know whether cometd client is connected to http or https, I need to log this information.

I am new to cometd and have not much idea about doing this.

One way I was thinking is to check for https in `bayeuxContext.getURL()`, but am not sure whether it will work or not.

Can somebody suggest on how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: can you check the port value?

Comment: Please augment your question: What software are you using? What have you tried so far? Etc. Usually a https in the URL will be enough to distinguish secure connection. Also why do you want to know? Wouldn't it be better to have the server redirect http to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `BayeuxContext.getURL()` will return the full URI the client used to connect to the server, and therefore will contain also the scheme that you can check whether it's `http` or `https`.

This will work for both HTTP-based and WebSocket-based transports. For WebSocket, the URI reported will be the URI of the initial HTTP upgrade request.

Comment: so if a http request upgrade to ws then also geturl will return initial http request (same with htts to wss) ?

Comment: I have observed that getURL returns upgraded request, so what can be done to identify initial request to be http or https)

Comment: The scheme of the URI will tell you whether it's HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: URL is returned as a string, if http is upgraded to ws then scheme will me ws only, and for https it would be wss, so you mean to check for https/wss in URL to count for https ?

Comment: The scheme will always be a HTTP one, so like I said, look for "http" or "https".

Comment: I have printed URI and it is ws when webscoket upgrade happend

Comment: That is correct, the URI has a ws or wss scheme in case of usage of the WebSocket transport, sorry for the confusion.